# how to locally develop angular cli builder

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have 2 folders on my machine, one Angular CLI project and one typescript project where I'm developing builders for the Angular CLI architects This is a mono repo and the builders are internal use only that I never plan on publishing. I have tried referencing the builders 4 diffrent ways:

relative:

```
/* angular.json */
{
  "projects": {
    "my-cli-proj": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "relative/path/to/my-builders:my-browser"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

install local module (file:):

```
/* package.json */
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "my-builders": "file:relative/path/to/my-builders"
  }
}

/* angular.json */
{
  "projects": {
    "my-cli-proj": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "my-builders:my-browser"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

<s>npm link (the "right" way)</s> (not an option see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13055#issuecomment-442815952)

run `npm link` in the my-builders folder and then `npm link my-builders` in the angular cli project folder

```
/* angular.json */
{
  "projects": {
    "my-cli-proj": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "my-builders:my-browser"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

npm pack:

run `npm pack` in the my-builders folder

```
/* package.json */
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "my-builders": "file:relative/path/to/my-builders-version.tgz"
  }
}

/* angular.json */
{
  "projects": {
    "my-cli-proj": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "my-builders:my-browser"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All ways but npm pack produce this misleading error on `ng build`

> Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
>   This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed. You can check this with `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, and then remove the extra copies.

output of `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`

```
`-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.8.3
  `-- @ngtools/webpack@6.2.3
```

Needing to run `npm pack` for every little change is not reasonable, is there a better way to develop the builder locally? (prefer the builders to be in their own project for separation).

duplication repo https://github.com/gatimus/builder-development

Edit:

I also tried

```
/* angular.json */
{
  "projects": {
    "my-cli-proj": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "my-builders:my-browser",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and `ng build --preserve-symlink`, same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you never plan on publishing then you could put the builders in /my-cli-proj/my-builders and instead of `"builder": "my-builders:my-browser"`, use `"builder": "./my-builders:my-browser"`,. I think that should work. You still need to compile your builder somehow, like with tsc directly.

According to this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13055#issuecomment-446643284) the builder should be in the same project.